# Sql select query returning Resource id #4

Tags: php, sql

I wrote the following code to select text from database,but when i echo the output it giving output as Resource id #4

```
mysql_select_db("xxxxx", $link);
$q = "SELECT start_of FROM `qr_table` WHERE id_qr =1";
$result = mysql_query ($q, $link);
echo $result;
```

i am new to sql,forgive me if its a stupid questain
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also .. please read the manual.

Comment: @tereško: thats a perfectly valid answer, why did you make it a comment?

Comment: @mizipzor because, IMHO, it was not a valid answer. I think that any user with 4K+ reputations (thus, with rights to close questions), should put some effort into creating an answer. I actually tend to downvote trivial answers, if they are provided by high-rep users, who are just rep-whoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are echoing out the connection. you need to do something with the results like loop through them please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read *at least* [Php documentation about Mysql query function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can't print out the result from MySQL directly. Try mysql_fetch_assoc(), which loads the value of each column into an associative array. if you have multiple rows returned, it will move to the next one each time it is called, and return false when there are no more.

Answer (score 0):

this help for you

```
<?php 
            $link=mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","")or die("Not connected".mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("test");
            $query="select * from qr_table";
            $result=mysql_query($query,$link)or die("Query failed".mysql_error());

            print "<center><table border=1>\n";
            while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            print "\t<tr>\n";
            foreach($line as $col_value){
                        print "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
                    } 
                    print "\t</tr>\n";
            }
            print "</table>\n</center>";

?>
```